# Filterings columns by striping column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this df:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'comp_1.10':[10,20],
                'comp_1.20':[20,30], 
                'comp_2.30':[30,40],
                'comp_1.90':[10,20],
                'teste'    :[40,30],
                'teste_1'  :[100,100]})
```

I want to filter all comp_1 columns regardless of `_10,_20`...in the column name, `where value = 10`

should return:

```
 teste   teste_1  comp_1.10  comp_1.90
   40      100       10        10
   30      100       Nan       Nan
```

I know I can use `a.query('column_1.10 = 10')`  but How can I get all column_1 ?

Comment: what do you mean by `column_1`?

Comment: columns names are column_1.10, column_1.20, column_1.90 , column_2.30 i want to filter all columns thats starts with column_1

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter()` method:

```
out=a.filter(like='_1').join(a['teste'])
#filter out columns that looks like '_1'
#since you also want 'teste' column so used join() method to get that column from a
```

Then:

```
teste=out.filter(like='teste').columns.tolist()
#filtered out columns like 'teste'
out=out.set_index(teste)
#make 'teste' as the index of dataframe out
out=out[out.eq(10)].dropna(axis=1,how='all').reset_index()
#checked your condition,filtered out result,droped NaN's and resetted index
```

Output of `out`:

```
    teste_1     teste   comp_1.10   comp_1.90
0   100         40      10.0        10.0
1   100         30      NaN         NaN
```

Comment: I also need comp_1 where values = 10 only @AnuragDabas

Comment: @pouchewar you want rows or columns or both? that satisfies this condition `comp_1 == 10 `

Answer (score 0):

Another way.  Fast.

```
a.loc[:,a.transpose().index.str.startswith('teste') |
        a.transpose().index.str.startswith('comp_1') &
        (a.transpose()==10).any(axis=1) ]

       comp_1.10  comp_1.90  teste  teste_1
0         10         10     40      100
1         20         20     30      100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = a.filter(like='comp_1')
df = a[['teste', 'teste_1']].join(
    out.mask(out != 10)
).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
#    teste  teste_1  comp_1.10  comp_1.90
# 0     40      100       10.0       10.0
# 1     30      100        NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
b = (a.set_index(a.columns[a.columns.str.contains('test')].tolist())
     .loc[:,lambda x: x.isin([10]).any()])
b = b.where(b.eq(10))
```

or

```
m = a.columns.str.startswith('comp_')

a.loc[:,(m & a.eq(10).any()) | ~m]
```